# Python Pandas - How to filter multiple columns by one value

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am doing analysis by pandas.
 
My table has 7M rows* 30 columns. Cell values are ranged from -1 to 3 randomly. Now I want to filter out rows based on columns' value.
 
I understand how to select based on multiple conditions, write down conditions and combine by "&" "|". 
But I have 30 columns to filter and filter by the same value. For instance, last 12 columns' value equals -1 need to be selected

```
df.iloc[:,-12:]==-1
```

The code above gives me a boolean. I need actual data frame. 
The logic here is "or", means if any column has value -1, that row needs to be selected.
Also, it is good to know what if I need "and", all columns have value -1? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the `OR` case, use [`DF.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) (returns `True` if **any** element is `True` along a particular axis):

```
df[(df.iloc[:,-12:] == -1).any(axis=1)]
```

For the `AND` case, use [`DF.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) (returns `True` if **all** elements are `True` along a particular axis):

```
df[(df.iloc[:,-12:] == -1).all(axis=1)]
```