# Filter columns by same value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample data-frame and I want to filter a few columns based on the same value but I want to avoid duplicating line to do this like:

```
df = df.loc[df['a'] == 7]
df = df.loc[df['b'] == 7]
```

I am looking for a more clean way to write this since I will have many columns with the same treatments. Here's my attempt:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 7, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c']) 
my_cols = ['a','b']
print(df.loc[df[my_cols]==7])
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot index with multidimensional key

Does anyone know if is it possible to make this type of filter?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711186/python-pandas-how-to-filter-multiple-columns-by-one-value

Comment: @PV8 - Can you find some better dupe? Because `iloc` here is not encessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `df[my_cols]==7` return boolean `DataFrame` is necessary add [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print(df[(df[my_cols]==7).any(axis=1)])
   a  b  c
2  7  7  9
```

---

```
print (df[my_cols]==7)
       a      b
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True   True
```